# Optional asterisk in elasticsearch.

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

This is my _search options in query. When I'm typing **wor** it will match word but when I'm searching for **word** it's not matching. If i'm typing anything else it's matching again. For example expression is **is this good** when i type **i** it will match, **is** will not match and **is t** will match again. My analyzer have this fields

```
"tokenizer": "standard",
"filter": [
    "english_possessive_stemmer",
    "lowercase",
    "english_stop",
    "english_stemmer"
  ]
```

I tried both text* and text*? but they are not working.

```
'query_string': {
    'split_on_whitespace': false,
    'query': `${text}*?`,
    'fields': ['group_title^20', 'description', 'tags.name']
}
```

So the question : how I can match for whole expression instead of one word without changing analyzer, if there is no option then how i can setup it with analyzer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doesn't this work? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html

Comment: Can you provide a more complete test case? (a gist with complete mapping, sample documents, queries that work and queries that doesn't)

Comment: @dayan-moreno-leon I can't use match as i need to start only from beginning of the title. So word can't be matched in the middle of the string.

Comment: @andrei-stefan Actually I can't, because of some confidence  reasons. But thanks for helping.

Comment: Then I can't help you.